# Склонение слова "жанр" в предложении

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильность склонения слова в предложении: я люблю книги\фильмы\сериалы в жанре\жанрах ужасы, триллер и детектив. Как всё-таки будет правильно: жанре или жанрах? (Переделать предложение не вариант, нужна именно эта формулировка).

И вот для примера ещё одно предложение:
Я беру с собой этот чайник и чашку. Этот или эти?

Можно, пожалуйста, подкрепить это каким-то правилом?

Answer (score 2):

1. *Я беру с собой **эти**  чайник и чашку.*

При использовании ед. числа  возникнет смысловая неопределенность: *Я беру с собой **этот**  чайник и чашку.* Если определение не относится к чашке, то лучше изменить предложение, например: *Я беру с собой этот чайник и какую-нибудь чашку.*

Правило Розенталя: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)

(1) Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме единственного числа, если **по смыслу сочетания ясно**, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например:

Дикий гусь и утка прилетели первыми (Тургенев); общий веселый говор и хохот (Л. Толстой); написать свой адрес, имя, отчество (А.Н. Толстой); Ее великолепная шуба и шляпка не произвели никакого впечатления (Чехов).

(2) Определение ставится в форме множественного числа, если по смыслу сочетания при единственном числе было бы неясно, связано ли определение с ближайшим существительным или со всем рядом однородных членов.

2. *Я люблю книги\фильмы\сериалы **в жанрах** ужасы, триллер и детектив.*

Здесь приложение "в жанрах" по смыслу можно приравнять к обобщающему слову, сравнить: *Я люблю книги\фильмы\сериалы **в следующих жанрах**: ужасы, триллер и детектив.*

Подобная тема рассматривается у Розенталя а разделе § 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения (пункт 4) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

Если однородным членам предложения, выраженным собственными именами лиц, предшествует общее для них приложение, не выступающее в роли обобщающего слова (при чтении в этом случае отсутствует характерная для произнесения обобщающего слова пауза), то двоеточие перед ними не ставится: Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян.